# How can I get junk in my trunk?

Tags: fallout-4

With the new crafting system, I've got a massive pile of junk in a wooden crate in my base. When I finish crafting things, I want to put all the junk away since I have no reason to carry it. Is there a way to move everything in the currently selected category from my inventory to a container? There is a "take all" button, but not a "store all" option that I can see. My enter key probably won't make it through the main story if I have to keep mashing it like I have been.

Comment: thatfrymeme.jpg

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Actually you can put all your junk directly in your workshop and just leave it there, you never have to pick it back up before crafting.

With all your junk in your inventory, simply interact with your workshop and press the button to "Store all junk" (Y on Xbox controller) and it will automatically store ALL your junk in your workshop. You can then still transfer some back to your inventory if you wish.

Normally this works only for a single settlement (junk/ressources are shared throughout every workshop/crafting station of said settlement) -- the junk is only where you've left it. You can however get "Local Leader" perks which enables you to set up trade routes which allow for sharing junk between settlements.

Comment: But that only works for one workshop, right? What if I want to use some of my stuff for weapon mods, some for armor mods, etc?

Comment: Still, that's really helpful and will save a lot of hassle

Comment: I am fairly sure the junk/resources are shared between all workshops/crafting stations, at least in the same base but I might be wrong (can't confirm how it works with other settlements either).

Comment: Can confirm -- all stations are linked PER SETTLEMENT.

Comment: Additionally, the local leader perk will allow you to establish "supply routes" which link the inventories of both town's crafting stations

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned in the existing answer, all junk can be deposited into your workshop store by approaching the store and pressing the Transfer button, then pressing the Transfer All Junk button.

However, there are a few things not mentioned in the existing answer that need clarification:

- All stores (workshop, weapons, armor, etc) share the same contents **per settlement**. This means if you have multiple settlements, contents in your store at one settlement will not be shared with another settlement
- You can [set up a supply line](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242665/52800) using spare settlers to share store contents between multiple settlements, this essentially makes everything in a store at a linked settlement available as though it was in the local store

Comment: What do you mean with 'per settlement'? Not long in the game I decided to put stuff in my workbench in the first settlement and could get it from any other settlement, like the Red Rocket. I have not had the supply line perk yet.

Comment: @Daniel - 'per settlement' means that your Workshop, Weapons bench, Armor Bench, Power Armor Station, Cooking Station, Chemistry Station etc ALL have access to the Workshop inventory. Anything stored in any of those stations/workshops can be accessed from any station within the same settlement.