# How to break down unwanted / unneeded items for crafting

Tags: fallout-4

Similar to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242690/how-can-i-break-items-down-into-their-components), but it only deals with *Junk* items and *Debris*.

What can I do to items that are not *Junk*, but also no longer needed / wanted, like *underpowered Guns*, *Ammo* for weapons I don't have, *Armor Pieces* that are just as good as no armor at all?

Comment: FWIW, I've greatly expanded my answer to the question that you referenced (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242690/how-can-i-break-items-down-into-their-components). Since it was a general question about components, the answer now covers how to get components from any item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can break down weapons and armor at the appropriate crafting station. So weapons at the weapons bench and armor at the armor bench.

Alternatively you can sell them to any vendor, if you don't need the materials, or need the caps more.

You might want to think about the Scrapper perk before breaking down weapons and armor, if you intend to take it at all I'd get it before you start breaking them down to take advantage of the extra material from the start.

Comment: I've found that the armor bench only lets you scrap armor that can be modified. Other kinds of armor need to be dropped on the ground and scrapped via the workshop interface.