# Does the workbench only auto-scrap junk?

Tags: fallout-4

Or also all your weapons and apparel that you store in it?

Comment: Took me a while to find that duplicate. Was pretty sure we had one.

Comment: FWIW, this is also answered in "Quick Summary" section of [How can I break items down into their components](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242690/how-can-i-break-items-down-into-their-components/242691#242691)?

Answer (score 1):

It will only automatically scrap junk.