# Can items found in Fallout 4, that are stored in different locations, be accessed in your players inventory?

Tags: fallout-4

When playing Fallout 4 your character can pick up many items using "A" on the controller. These items are spread through out the "Commonwealth". As the items accumulate they add weight to the point your character cannot run or "fast travel" to other locations. At that point you can transfer & store these in chests, workshops, etc found everywhere so you then reduce the weight & can once again run. One can also transfer some to a companion.My question is if you end up storing your found items all over the Commonwealth can you access **all** the items from you characters arm piece (B) inventory? or do you need to return to the transferred/stored locations to use the items for crafting, cooking, shooting, & building?

Comment: This looks like a dupe, but I already spent more time looking for a fitting question that it will take me to just answer it.

Comment: Relevant questions/dupe candidates: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243890/108003, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242665/108003, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242808/108003, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/244053/108003, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/244655/108003

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Items stored in a crafting station will be shared among all crafting stations in the immediate area. This is mostly only relevant in settlements. If you drop stuff off in power armor station in the middle of Lexington, it will stay there until you go get it.

Within settlements, anything stored in one bench can be utilized for crafting or removed **within that settlement.**

If you set up a supply line between settlements, you'll be able to use any junk or aid items to craft with at any connected settlements, but you can only **remove** stored items at the settlement they are actually stored at.

In other words, if you put a bunch of duct tape in the armor bench in Sanctuary, you can use it at Red Rocket if you have a supply line between them, but you can't take the duct tape out at Red Rocket and carry it somewhere else.

If you put a 10mm pistol into the armor bench at Sanctuary, you can take it out of the weapon bench in Sanctuary, but it will never be available at Red Rocket.

Comment: This answer is missing an answer: "No, you can't access them in your pip-boy inventory."

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot retrieve items that are not within your reach with your pip-boy. You will be required to travel back to recover your items.