# How to move settlers between settlements

Tags: fallout-4

In fallout 4 it'd make sense if you can move all your settlers to one 'main' base rather than having everyone spread out, as no one location has enough settlers to run all the stores etc.

How do I tell settlers to go to another settlement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Moving settlers from one settlement to the next works just like [setting up a supply line](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/242669/46740), only instead of choosing `SUPPLY LINE` you need to choose `MOVE`.

[image: Settler options in workshop mode]
<sup>Image originating from @[kalina](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/52800/kalina)'s answer linked above.</sup>

After that, you'll get a list of settlements to choose from.

It is possible that the settlement you want to send them to is grayed out, however. This can happen when the settlement is full.

Comment: 'In order to set up a supply line you need to have the Local Leader perk'.. ah so that's what I'm missing.

Comment: @djsmiley2k. The *Local Leader* perk is for setting up a supply line, though. It shouldn't be needed in order to move settlers around.

Comment: Seems it was my idiocy of not noticing the 'this settler cannot leave this location' message that was preventing me sending them elsewhere :<